How do I insert content from one Word document into another using python-docx-template?
I'm working on a project that automates the creation of some Word document reports that can get a little formatting-heavy. The body of the report consists of a bunch of entries for tests run, and what that looks like varies for different tests. It's important that the entry format is user-editable, and the best solution I've come up with as to how to implement that is to have a folder full of separate documents (for organization) for each test - these are edited by users and the correct entry is inserted into the document on report generation. Here are a few screenshots that explain this a little better:
This is the relevant part of the template document. Ideally, the {{ item.content }} tag would be replaced with the content from the corresponding entry document.

This is an example of what an entry document would look like after being edited by a user. Note the formulas and numbered list (other entries would include things like images, tables, etc.)

A simple copy-paste in Word gives the desired result when editing manually, with all styles, formatting, and content preserved. The second picture is after pasting the content into the template document:


And finally, the unedited entry template document:

Any advice on how to do this using python-docx-template? I haven't been able to find a way to do something other than recreating all the formatting manually, which would be very difficult given the variation between entries for different tests. I've also thought about circumventing the template package entirely and trying to edit the document XML, but I'm sure there is a much better solution out there than that. Thanks!
